# How to add files inside temporary directory in JUnit

Tags: java, file, junit

I found two ways to create temporary directories in JUnit.

Way 1:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder tempDirectory = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void testTempDirectory() throws Exception {
    tempDirectory.newFile("test.txt");
    tempDirectory.newFolder("myDirectory");
    // how do I add files to myDirectory?
}
```

Way 2:

```
@Test
public void testTempDirectory() throws Exception {
    File myFile = File.createTempFile("abc", "txt");
    File myDirectory = Files.createTempDir();
    // how do I add files to myDirectory?
}
```

As the comment above mentions, I have a requirement where I want to add some temporary files in these temporary directories. Run my test against this structure and finally delete everything on exit.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it the same way you do it for real folders.

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder rootFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void shouldCreateChildFile() throws Exception {
    File myFolder = rootFolder.newFolder("my-folder");

    File myFile = new File(myFolder, "my-file.txt");
}
```

Comment: Note that the "my-file.txt" will only be an in-memory File.

Answer (score 2):

Using new File(subFolderOfTemporaryFolder, "fileName") did not work for me. Calling subFolder.list() returned an empty array. This is how I made it work:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void createFileInSubFolderOfTemporaryFolder() throws IOException {
    String subFolderName = "subFolder";
    File subFolder = temporaryFolder.newFolder(subFolderName);
    temporaryFolder.newFile(subFolderName + File.separator + "fileName1");

    String[] actual = subFolder.list();

    assertFalse(actual.length == 0);
}
```

Comment: This solved it for me as well, the accepted answer did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using TemporaryFolder creates a directory with a common root. Once you have created a folder, you can then create a file by specifying the directory structure and the final filename as the name.

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder rootFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void shouldCreateChildFile() throws Exception {
    File myFolder = rootFolder.newFolder("my-folder");
    File myFileInMyFolder = rootFolder.newFile("/my-folder/my-file.txt");
}
```

You can create child directories in the same way.

Answer (score -3):

There two ways to delete temp directory or temp file.Fist,delete the  dirctory or file manually use file.delete() method,Second,delete the temp directory or file when program exis user file.deleteOnExist().
You can try this,I print the path to console,you can to check realy delte or not,I test on windows7 system.

```
File myDirectory = Files.createTempDir();
File tmpFile = new File(myDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "test.txt");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(tmpFile, "HelloWorld", "UTF-8");
System.out.println(myDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
// clean
tmpFile.delete();
myDirectory.deleteOnExit();
```